# Injective and surjective functions $\mathbb N \to\mathbb Z$

Tags: functions

Are there any injective but not surjective functions from natural numbers to integers? Are there surjective but non-injective functions $\mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$? I’m having a hard time coming up with anything…

Comment: Yes, many. For example $f(n)=n$ injective but not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Sure--$f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x) = x$ is injective,  but doesn't map to $\mathbb{Z}\setminus \mathbb{N}$. But because $\mathbb{N}\subset \mathbb{Z}$ is proper, the existence of such a map is not surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Example, $f(n)=n$ is injective but not surjective.

Example for a map $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is surjective but not injective:

$f(n)=$
$$0 \text{ if } n=1, 2, 3, ..., 10,$$
$$k \text{ if } n=2k+9, k=1, 2, ...$$
$$-k \text{ if } n= 2k+10, k=1,2,...$$

Answer (score 0):

$f(n) = (-1)^n \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ is surjective but not injective (since it takes value $0$ twice).  On the other hand, $(-1)^n \lceil n/2 \rceil$ is bijective.